# Different Extensions of the Web Page

Tags: html

In this, 
    http: / / localhost:8080  /myWebPageProj/HelloWorld.jsp

NOTE THE EXTENSION in the link , which ends with ".jsp"

And also many web pages end with .html , .htm ,..

But some pages like the below

> http://www.w3schools.com/
>
> https://www.google.co.in/

has no extension? **What kind of pages are they?** ****Why they dont have any extension?****

Answer (score 0):

Index.html is the default page that will be returned to a user who request the urls like https://www.google.co.in

Comment: But `index.html` is not guaranteed to be the page that the root domain forwards on to, especially in the context where they're being served up as JSPs.